# Discord py get input

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Hey is there a way to get in a bot input and send with this a message?

```
@client.event
async def on_ready:
    while True:
        i = input("$")
        print(i)
```

But if I run this, the bot doesn't react anymore to normal commands ...

Thatswhy I tried with threading, but there was the problem that I couldn't interact with the discord py api, because the functions are all async.

Comment: Are you trying to get input from the members in the guild or from the person running the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is a blocking function, there are two ways of running it in a non-blocking way

1. Using `loop.run_in_executor`

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready:
    while True:
        i = await client.loop.run_in_executor(None, input, "$")
        print(i)
```

*Using this method is not possible to pass kwargs, if you need them please leave a comment and I'll edit my answer*

2. Using `aioconsole.ainput`, Install it with the following command

```
pip install aioconsole
```

To use it

```py
from aioconsole import ainput

@client.event
async def on_ready:
    while True:
        i = await ainput("$")
        print(i)
```

[`aioconsole` pypi](https://pypi.org/project/aioconsole/)

Also this will get input from the CONSOLE, not from discord. If you want that you can use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: Thank you very much :)